# How to add a BIT column in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, bit, toad

I want to add a BIT column to a table. I have provided the statement to do so, but an error declares the BIT in my statement as a invalid datatype. What would be the correct way to add a bit column?

```
ALTER TABLE Persons 
    ADD is_person BIT NULL
```

Comment: It works fine [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf6f73b845140725e11fb98a41b6da0a)

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

[You should specify database you use; this is Oracle example, see if it helps].

There's no such a datatype in Oracle, so you'd use `NUMBER` and constrain it:

```
SQL> create table persons
  2    (id   number,
  3     bit  number(1,0) check (bit in (0, 1))   --> this
  4    );

Table created.
```

A few examples:

```
SQL> insert into persons (id, bit) values (1, 2);
insert into persons (id, bit) values (1, 2)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C008434) violated


SQL> insert into persons (id, bit) values (1, 1);

1 row created.
   
SQL> insert into persons (id, bit) values (1, 0);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into persons (id, bit) values (1, 10);
insert into persons (id, bit) values (1, 10)
                                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column


SQL>
```

---

Or, if you'd want to add it (as table already exists), then

```
alter table persons add bit number(1, 0) check (bit in (0, 1));
```

Comment: I think it is SQL Server. `SQL Server BIT data type is an integer data type that can take a value of 0, 1, or NULL .`